# Installing ubuntu on MacBook Pro 9,1

Tags: 12.04, macbook-pro

I bought a MacBook Pro 9,1 (Mid 2012, 15inch, NOT retina). Can anyone tell me how to install Ubuntu 12.04 on it? I already have Windows installed via BootCamp. Also, where to install drivers for Ubuntu and all? This link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro has nothing for 9,1 so please help me. If I have to remove BootCamp and reinstall Windows manually because BootCamp doesn't allow resizing of partitions, that's fine. Please tell me how to install Precise on MBP 9,1

Thanks!

Comment: You might check http://askubuntu.com/questions/157514/installing-ubuntu-12-04-on-macbook-pro9-2?rq=1

Comment: What is "9,1" suppose to mean? When referring to MacBooks the year and screen size, or generation is usually mentioned.

Comment: Added the year and screen size @YiJiang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works for me (13.04 and above work well on a Mac):

1. Install Ubuntu with the 64-bit ISO.
2. For wireless drivers and NVIDIA drivers, go to `Additional Drivers` and install them.

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to just install it on a flash drive and before it shows the apple boot logo, hold option key and select the flash drive. It performs surprisingly fast off a flash drive. I have a cousin that uses this method on his Mac.

Comment: But I want to do it on a partition. Could you tell how?

Answer (score 1):

I have one of these and have still not got it all working properly. However I have managed to get Mint 13 (derived from 12.04) installed on it. The basic setup that you are asking about is described [here](http://lifehacker.com/5531037/how-to-triple+boot-your-mac-with-windows-and-linux-no-boot-camp-required). In order to get an Ubuntu live image to boot you need to pass some options to the kernel as described [here](http://philatwarrimoo.blogspot.co.nz/2012/06/unubtu-1204-on-macbook-pro-91-non.html) in the section entitled 3rd attempt. I could only get it to boot from a DVD, it wouldn't work from a USB drive for me.

As I understand it, if you want to have Windows also then you can't use EFI boot, but the default install uses BIOS boot so that shouldn't require further config.

There is further discussion about this laptop on ubuntuforums.org (AU won't let me post any more links so you'll have to search) full support for it still seems to be a work in progress.

The key thing about booting from CD or HD in BIOS mode is to add "noapic" to the kernel boot parameters otherwise it will not boot. For EFI mode you need "noinitremap".

Comment: Can we interact on email?

Comment: It's probably better if you use the forum then everyone can benefit [have a look at these threads](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aubuntuforums.org+macbook+pro+9%2C1).

Comment: I only asked for email so that you could give the link (because AU isn't allowing you)

Comment: How to add noapic to kernel boot parameters?

Answer (score 0):

So i just installed an almost "perfect" MacbookPro 9.1. A pretty long process but completely worth it! Here we go:

Install 12.10 
-use the 64 bit version on the default download page -it has EFI boot support ie: ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso.
-Download and install Refind on your macbook pro.
-Hold down Option key during booting the macbook pro and insert the DVD/CD. Wait for it to be read and select "EFI Boot" NOT "Windows"

Upgrade To 13.04 (Its Pretty Stable For Me :) using for Java development)
-Install and update your 12.10 completely.
-Once 12.10 is installed and updated, upgrade to 13.04 using:
 sudo do-release-upgrade -d
[it should now download the 13.04 packages and upgrade. Everything worked for me out of the box except my wireless]

Install Wireless:
After a few searching and trials, i found this thread "http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966236" ...that did it for me.

Suffice it to say that i'm writing this using the macbook now :)
Enjoy.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu - the BIOS one not EFI install because I use Windows too and apparently you can't triple boot 3 EFI OSes :(

Comment: One more thing, were you able to install NVidia's drivers? I'm currently using X.org's drivers.

Comment: i didn't have to do all that with my approach. i'm comfortable working with just Mountain Lion and Ubuntu. It will take some work, i admit, so if u are up to it, then jump on!!! otherwise i will suggest waiting for the release from Canonical. Enjoy.

Comment: Well I use all 3 :P Thanks for the help anyway. Much appreciated!

Comment: Happy for you man, Wow!!!! Can you help? It can sleep and hibernate but it does not seem to resume after. I always have to restart(AND LOOSE MY WORK) after that.

Comment: Even I restart, lose my work. Hence, I never put it to sleep.

Comment: Yeah that's what i've been too - I never put it to sleep or hibernate. I already asked this question "NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M Not Resuming After Suspend" but no respose on it yet.

Comment: But you said previously you're able to put it to sleep?

Comment: That was 12.04 on Macbook Pro 8,1.

Comment: Oh ok :) Btw, 13.04 runs brilliant on 9,1. NVIDIA and wireless drivers can be installed from Additional Drivers :D And hibernate works !!!

Comment: Hibernate works?!!!!! U mean u use `GK107M [GeForce GT 650M Mac Edition]`? please confirm this for me using 'lshw -C Display'. On standby.

Comment: Whiles you're at it, do specify the NVIDIA binary u selected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 310. the first one in the list. sudo pm-hibernate worked. then i followed the ubuntu manual to add hibernation to power options

Comment: it worked great! thanks. Now i've everything functional. Hey try the `tlp` project, its a good battery energy saver. Read on it at [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html). Hope it helps you.

Comment: Does your microphone work?

Answer (score 0):

I have a non retina macbook pro 9,1 as well. I followed the installation instructions for a mbp on the ubuntu website (with refit), but after the installation would complete, I'd reboot, and after passing the grub screen, get an unresponsive black screen.

The solution I found to get a good install is to remove all nvidia drivers after installation and before reboot, via `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`. I don't know exactly why this worked for me, but it did.

I also changed the grub option `"quiet splash"` to `"nomodeset"`, and ran `update-grub` after.

After these steps, I rebooted, and everything worked perfectly!  Hope this helps.

Comment: on Ubuntu 13.04, NVIDIA drivers install perfectly.